# How to replicate the between_time function of Pandas in PySpark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to replicate the `between_time` function of Pandas in PySpark.
Is it possible since in Spark the dataframe is distributed and there is no indexing based on datetime?

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='1D20min')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=i)
ts.between_time('0:45', '0:15')
```

Is something similar possible in PySpark?

[pandas.between_time - API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a timestamp column, say `ts`, in a Spark dataframe, then for your case above, you can just use

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(F.hour(F.col('ts')).between(0,0) & F.minute(F.col('ts')).between(15,45))
```